# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in Chrome extension - message from content to background to popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a small chrome extension and am currently stuck with displaying some information gathered from the code in the popup. The information gathered from my other functions can be displayed fine, but for some reason for the function where I have to use the content script to get the information and send it to the background script to display it I just can't make it work.
The message shows up correctly in the console when received. When I try to modify the innerHTML of the targeted paragraph with a test string, it works fine. I have tried a bunch of different orders of variables and functions as well, but it doesn't seem to matter at all. Can anyone help me out with this?

**contentscript.js**

```js
function messageBackground(e) {
    var arr = secHeaders();
    console.log(arr)
    var sending = chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        headers: arr
    })
}

messageBackground();
```

**background.js**

```js
var secHeaders = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
   httpChecker();
   cookieControl();
   sslTest();
   document.getElementById("secHeaderA").innerHTML = secHeaders;
}

function handleMessage(request, sender) {
      console.log("message from content script:   " + request.headers);
      secHeaders = request.headers;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
```

EDIT:

**manifest.json**

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Security Analysis Extension",
    "version": "0.001",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_start",
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["blocked_domains.js", "jquery-3.4.1.min.js", "background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "extension_icon.png",
        "default_title": "Security Analysis Extension",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "cookies",
        "webRequest",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "background.js"
    ]
}
```

Comment: is it possible that handleMessage() runs after document.getElementById("secHeaderA").innerHTML = secHeaders; so that secHeaders is still an empty array?

Comment: The background scripts run in a hidden background page so your code doesn't do anything meaningful. Alternatively, you're loading background.js in the wrong place. Either way, you'll need to rework it. For example send a message from popup.js to the tab, the tab will respond with the data, the popup will show it in the callback. See [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). If you need assistance, show manifest.json and describe the desired workflow in more detail.

Comment: @wOxxOm T added the manifest.json. Basically the current idea is that a function in the content script returns some information, which is then sent to the bg script. Afterwards I want to display that information in a popup window when I click on the extension icon in Chrome. Right now I don't have a popup.js file, but only a popup.html file. I was also considering to modify the content script function so that I can make it work within the background script, but I don't know if that would fix anything.

Comment: 1) You'll need to add popup.js to your popup.html and inside that js file you can send a message to the content script as I suggested, no need for background script for this.  2) exposing background.js via web_accessible_resources means you're doing something wrong, 3) background.js doesn't have access to any visible DOM because it runs in the hidden background page with its own empty DOM. 4) content scripts run only in web pages so I don't see how it access `sec` headers if these are http headers - these can only be obtained in an extension script e.g. background.js

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to append to your document when a message is received?

```
function handleMessage(request, sender) {
      console.log("message from content script:   " + request.headers);
      document.getElementById("secHeaderA").innerHTML = request.headers;
}
```

In general `$(document).ready(function(){` will run immediately when background.js loads. If `handleMessage` has not been called yet and `secHeaders` set then the innerHTML would be set to an empty array.

Another issue maybe that `secHeaders` does not contain valid HMTL string. Maybe try converting secHeaders to a JSON string and inspect the output:

```
document.getElementById("secHeaderA").innerText = JSON.stringify(secHeaders);
```